# Spyder4 how to open files called in a code

Tags: python, ide, spyder

I have a list of functions stored in a file called functions.py. I will call them in the main program file. I tried all means but I do not know how to open it. When in Spyder 3, I hover over the file name in the program and would do ctrl+right click to open it. It does not work here in Spyder 4.

My code in a file called Mainfile.py

```
# import function file
from functions import *
```

Comment: What's the path of the mainfile.py and the functions folder?

Comment: @User Yes! both are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is caused by a [bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/14236) in Spyder 4. We plan to fix that in our next version (4.2.1), to be released in a month and a half.